# Decoding Assembly Language (Bomb Lap Phase 7)

Tags: c

Solving assembly but one line is tripping me up:

```
0x804a440(,%eax, 4), %eax
```

I know the hex value is 10. So is it saying that 10+4, repeated?

Comment: What hex value are you talking about?  `%eax` is a _register_.

Comment: Yes. But what does this code mean? Doesn't 4 multiply to the value in eax?